# How to retrieve vertex coordinates of a 2D/3D shape in processing?

Tags: python, processing

I have a shape rotating in 3D space in Processing. I want to print out the current coordinates of the shape in the physical 2D space. Here's the code:

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
sqr = 0

def setup():
    size(600, 600, P3D)
    frameRate(24)
    lights()


def draw():
    background('#5099ff')
    global x, y, z, sqr
    translate(300, 300)

    pushMatrix()
    rotateY(mouseX/(20*PI))
    rotateX(-mouseY/(20*PI))


    box(100)
    popMatrix()

    translate(0, -200)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    noFill()
    sqr += .1
    rotateY(sqr)
    rotateZ(sqr)
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

At any instantaneous point although the square has its own 3D coordinates which I could calculate, how would I get the physical pixel location on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions?

From [the reference](https://py.processing.org/reference/screenX.html):

> Takes a three-dimensional X, Y, Z position and returns the X value for where it will appear on a (two-dimensional) screen.

To go the other way and convert from screen coordinates to 3D space, you could use the `modelX()`, `modelY()`, and `modelZ()` functions.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://py.processing.org/reference/).